# Trouble generating a Tuple from comprehension in inline assignment

Tags: python

I'm having trouble assigning the return of a lambda expression to an object when returning a tuple - it works when returning a list though.

This is working perfect:

```
roots = lambda a,b,c: [(-b + i * sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a) for i in (-1,1)]
```

This isn't working as I expect:

```
roots = lambda a,b,c: ((-b + i * sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a) for i in (-1,1))
```

Comment: You're right I always forget. using `lambda a,b,c: tuple((-b + i ...` worked as expected

Comment: You are not creating a tuple. What you are using is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: have you considered to print the result of the lambda and see that it is not a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written a generator expression. If you want to return tuple you can pass the generator expression to `tuple` like this:

```
roots = lambda a,b,c: tuple((-b + i * sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a) for i in (-1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept called tuple comprehension. It is called generators. The above code invokes the generator. Hence you are unable to get your desired result.